# NodaTime: Replicating DateTime.Today

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, nodatime

My service requests data from an external service that needs an argument for a particular date (doesn't need time information).

Until now, I've been using DateTime.Today (e.g. 10/24/2014 12:00:00).

I've moved to using NodaTime for improved testability but not sure of the best way to replicate this functionality:

```
public class SomeClass(IClock clock)
{
    _clock = clock; //Injected at runtime, provides mockable interface

    var localNow = _clock.Now.InZone(_serverTimeZone);
    var today = localNow.ToDateTimeUnspecified().Date; //This close enough? Seems kinda long
}
```

Comment: 3, 2, 1, 0...JS will magically appear!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Was already writing my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To represent a date, you should use `LocalDate` rather than `DateTime`, ideally. So you want:

```
var localNow = clock.Now.InZone(serverZone);
var today = localNow.Date;
```

If you *must* use `DateTime`, then your current code is fine.

In Noda Time 2.0, this will be simpler due to a `ZonedClock` which is basically a composite of a clock and a time zone, allowing you to write:

```
// Or whatever...
private readonly ZonedClock zonedClock = clock.InZone(zone);

// Then later

LocalDate date = zonedClock.GetCurrentDate();
```

Noda Time 2.0 isn't ready for release yet, but I wanted to give you an idea of what's coming.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm the first in my organization to jump on the Noda bandwagon so everyone is still using plain ole' DateTimes. Good to hear about 2.0 changes, though. 

Like many things, Noda is great when you're all in, but when you leave the walled garden things get a little wonky.Love this library so far, though!

Comment: @Killnine: You could consider adding an extension method to `IClock`, e.g. `DateTime GetCurrentDate(this IClock clock, DateTimeZone zone)`.